# Usage of consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Controller class:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/save", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
        @Transactional
        public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("registerDetails") TestingDTO destingDTO,
                                 BindingResult result, ModelAndView model, HttpServletRequest request) throws ServiceProviderException {
```

JSP file:

```
<form method="post" id="testingForm" name="testingForm" modelAttribute="registerDetails" action="save" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

In the form, the user will be uploading a profile picture image, thus I am using the consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}) to save the data, however, I noticed that if I uses the consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}, the modelAttribute that is passed to the controller class will be empty, may I know how can I solve this ?

I am added the

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1048576"/>
    </bean>
```

As I am just trying to save the image, I am not including the `MultipartFile` in the method, may I know how can I solve this ?

Comment: You can remove it, because you don't send a data along with multipart form.

Comment: Can I still remove it if other than Image is being saved, such as a string field ?

Comment: You are not able to pass it along with the form data.

Comment: If thats the case, can you provide me with a link or sources on how I can tackle on this ? Because I dont see any documentation saying that I cant send a String field along with a multipart form

Comment: The documentation won't ever say that you can send String field in the model attribute.

Comment: Hi, it seems I am able to send String field in the model attribute

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by placing the

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" 
class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1048576"/>
    </bean>
```

under the Servlet-xml